# Deleting from an array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, I'm trying to delete from an array if it's element value isn't equal to a value that I specified:

Code: http://pastebin.com/hUc3mVLv

```
$scope.enablePVR = function()
{
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.new_epg.length; i++) {
                start_time = convert_time($scope.new_epg[i].start);
                $scope.new_epg[i].title = $scope.new_epg[i].title.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
                $scope.new_epg[i].description = "";
                $scope.new_epg[i].time = start_time;
        }
        archiveEPG = [];
        for(var i=0; i<archiveEPG.length; i++) {
                var e = document.getElementById("dateSelect");
                if($scope.new_epg[i].start.split(" ")[0] == e[e.selectedIndex].value) {
                        archiveEPG[archiveEPG.length+1] = $scope.new_epg[i];
                }
        }
        document.getElementById("dateSelect").remove(0);
        $scope.get_epg(null, true, archiveEPG);
}
```

Comment: Please paste relevant code in the question

Comment: tips: `for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++)`

Comment: instead of PasteBin have you through about throwing it up on Plnkr so we can see and test whats happening ?

Comment: diEcho is right so length isn't calculated each time.

Comment: [This may help u](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Comment: Where do you try to remove element from an array in your code? The only thing that indicates a _remove_ is `document.getElementById("dateSelect").remove(0);`, but that is an `DOMElement` and not an `Array`.

Comment: The part that is not working is in the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

`.remove(0)` isn't valid you can add this function to make it valid tho :

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(index) {
    return this.splice(index, 1); // The second parameter is the number of elements to remove.
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to rename `value` to `index`

Comment: is `.shift()` not well supported on browsers?

Comment: If it isn't a polyfill you shouldn't extend the prototype of _language Objects_. Beside that `.remove(0)` is called on a DOMElement and not on an array.